# Read proto partly instead of full parsing in java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I used to define a `proto` file, for example

```
option java_package = "proto.data";
message Data {
    repeated string strs = 1;
    repeated int ints = 2;
}
```

I received from network this object's inputstream (or bytes). Then, normally, I do a parsing like `Data.parserFrom(stream)` or `Data.parserFrom(bytes)` to get the object.

By this, I have to hold full memory on Data object while I just need travel
all string and integer values in the object. It's bad when the object size is big.

What should I do for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to parse just part of a protobuf. If you want to be sure that you've seen *all* of the `strs` or *all* of the `ints`, you have to parse the entire message, since the values could appear in any order or even interleaved.

If you only care about memory usage and not CPU time then you could, in theory, use a hand-written parser to parse the message and ignore fields that you don't care about. You still have to do the work of parsing, you can just discard them immediately rather than keeping them in memory. However, to do this you'd need to study the [Protobuf wire format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) and write your own parser. You can use Protobuf's `CodedInputStream` class but a lot of work still needs to be done manually. The Protobuf library really isn't designed for this.

If you are willing to consider using a different protocol framework, [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org) is extremely similar in design to Protobufs but features in the ability to read only the part of the message you care about. Cap'n Proto incurs no overhead for the fields you don't examine, other than obviously the bandwidth and memory to receive the raw message bytes. If you are reading from a file, and you use memory mapping (`MappedByteBuffer` in Java), then only the parts of the message you actually use will be read from disk.

(Disclosure: I am the author of most of Google Protobufs v2 (the version you are probably using) as well as Cap'n Proto.)

Comment: Is there an easier way to parse data based on the data version? I put a **version** field in proto, corresponding to different proto parser, and wanna read the **version** firstly.

Comment: @Crawl.W Have an outer message type which is a `oneof` of all your versions.

Comment: "outer message" mean outer of the version-specific data? And then full parse to get the version number by any version proto (all them have the version field) , then parse it use the corresponding version proto?

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all. I am saying have a mesasge like `message VersionedMesasge { oneof version { Version1 version1 = 1; Version2 version2 = 2; Version3 version3 = 3; } }` Where `Version1`, `Version2`, etc. are the different versions of your message. You would NOT have a version number field inside each message, because the `oneof` replaces it. Now the protobuf parser "just works" and knows how to parse the correct version without any tricks.

Comment: **oneof** very useful and worked for me. But it's kind of like a patch, just for fields, and the `verion` field would be wider applicability and more flexibility, it could for one message even whole root message.As you said, proto doesn't support partial parsing, may it's a trade-off.

Comment: To be clear I'm not saying to put `oneof` around individual fields that changed, I'm saying to put it around the entire message, so the different members of the `oneof` represent different versions of the whole protocol. I think this is equivalent to the idea of a "version field" but it works today without any parser tricks.

Comment: Huh, adding `oneof` later only needs to keep the id consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. It appears that it may be already implemented but not adequately documented.
Has you tested it ?

See for discussion: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/7vTGDHe0ZyM

See also, sample test code in google's github:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/4644f99d1af4250dec95339be6a13e149787ab33/java/src/test/java/com/google/protobuf/lazy_fields_lite.proto